# ROS with Windows 10, How to find the right Commands

Tags: windows-10, ros

I am an absolute beginner to Ros and i have a very simple Question. Curiously i coudn´t find an answer yet: 
I want to use ROS for Windows 10 (with Visual Studio). Windows Version 19.04. The commands out of the Tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) do not work within the x64-Terminal or the selfcreated ROS-Terminal of Course. Is there a way to use them in Windows or another tutorial for Windows?

Thanks for your help and sorry for the simple question!

Comment: Google is your friend: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

Answer (score 0):

I think this documents are helpful for biginner to ROS on Windows.Please note that there are many big differents between ROS 1 and ROS 2 on Windows.

[Bringing the intelligent edge to robots with ROS on Windows 10 and Azure.](https://microsoft.github.io/Win-RoS-Landing-Page/#)

[ROS for Windows](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/index.html)

[Installing ROS 2 on Windows](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Windows-Install-Binary/#id3)